# Creating new QGIS Data Source Uri

Tags: qgis, python

I've added vectorlayer from database using the following code

```
# Create New Qgis Data source uri
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(database_connection['host'],
                  database_connection['port'],
                  database_connection['database'],
                  self.db_user, self.db_password)

uri.setDataSource(schemaname, tablename, geometrycolumn, query)
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), tablename, "postgres")
vlayer = self.iface.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), tablename, "postgres")
```

I'm unable to edit the attribute or geometry of the layer that is getting added. The below is the capability string for the layer

```
print(caps_string)
# Add Features, Add Attributes, Delete Attributes, Rename Attributes, 
# Fast Access to Features at ID, Presimplify Geometries, 
# Presimplify Geometries with Validity Check, Transactions, Curved Geometries
```

Could you please guide me on how to change the capability of the layer to include changing attributes and geometry?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by adding the primary key column while  adding the datasource

```
.uri.setDataSource(schemaname, tablename,  geometrycolumn,  query,  primarykeycolumn)
```